# Sending SMSes by Unification Engine?

Tags: api, sms, unificationengine

While Unification Engine seems to support sending SMSes, I am unable to find any documentation on that issue.

Does anyone have any idea what the format/syntax of Unification Engine with regards with dealing with SMSes?

Answer (score 1):

add sms connection

curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/connection/add -u USER_ACCESSKEY:USER_ACCESSSECRET --data '{"uri":"sms://ACCESS_TOKEN:ACCESS_SECRET@sms.com","name":"UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER"}' -k

to send sms

curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/message/send  --data "{ \"message\": { \"receivers\": [{\"name\": \"name\", \"address\": \"+PHONE_NUMBER_WITH_COUNTRYCODE\" , \"Connector\": \"sms\"}],\"sender\": {\"address\": \"+SENDER_PHONE_NUMBER_WITH_COUNTRYCODE\"},\"parts\": [{\"id\": \"1\",\"contentType\": \"text/plain\", \"data\":\"MESSAGE_BODY\" ,\"size\": MESSAGE_BODY_SIZE,\"type\": \"body\",\"sort\":0}]}}" -u USER_ACCESSKEY:USER_ACCESSSECRET -k

Comment: How does one get the sms.com credentials

Comment: ACCESS_TOKEN:ACCESS_SECRET where do these come from?